# Custom ZendRestController URL

Tags: php, web-services, zend-framework, rest

Iam developing a Zend RestController and i have to generate the response as xml format.
I added context switching and hence i could see my xml output with the url like:

**http://localhost/app/public/api/key/123456/format/xml/**

(where "api" is controller, key=123456, passed via GET)

But what i want is, the url should be something like:

**http://localhost/app/public/api/v1/abc.xml/**

(For the moment, leave the "key" parameter, as later i would be sending it through curl post)

How can i achieve this? Do i need to tweak something with the url? Iam mainly concerned with changing the "format/xml" to "abc.xml"

Comment: `http://localhost/app/public/api/key/123456/format/xml/` --- this url doesn't follow the REST ideology. The more appropriate is `http://localhost/app/public/api/keys/123456.xml`

Comment: I tried with the url: localhost/app/public/api/keys/123456.xml and i had to explode the "keys" to get the number (for using in my query). But now, i could not get the output format as xml. Unless i specify "/format/xml" at the end of url, iam not getting xml output. Is there any way ?

Comment: You need a Regex Route set up

Comment: Thanks jakenoble, however i got the xml format after adding: Content-type: text/xml at the top of the corresponding phtml view file :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have routes setup in my application bootstrap as:

```
/*
 * ReWrite Rules and Routes
 */
protected function _initRoutes() {
    $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
    // New Route
    $router->addRoute('api', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/api/:key.xml', array( 'module'=>'index', 'controller' => 'api', 'action' => 'index', 'key'=>'')));
}
```

And then use the url helper as:

```
<a href="<?= $this->url(array('key'=>123456), 'api') ?>">API Call</a>
```